# Which version of PostgreSQL installer would work in Mac Big Sur ver 11.6.1?

Tags: postgresql, installation, macos-big-sur

Despite attempts with PostgreSQL installer 14.1, 13.5, 12.9, 11.15, 10.14 on my Mac, I still face the same problem:
"Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
The database cluster initialisation failed."

Answer (score 0):

i think it is error due to missing some component. You need to read the installation log to know the details of the error